# Loading image appears only after 3rd click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

In my application, I have a loader image which should be displayed on link click for sorting. But the image doesn't appear for the first two clicks initially. The image appears after the third click. How can I show the loader image from the first click onwards?

My code:

```
function pleaseWait() {
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h2 style="padding:10px"><img src="../resources/images/ToolTip/ajax-loader.gif"/>Loading...</h2>', timeout: 50000 });
}

$('#ContentPlaceHolder2_GVMerchantByDivisionWithContact tbody th a').click(function (event) {
    $('#txtConformMessageValue').val("No");
    pleaseWait();
});
```

Comment: how large is your image ?

Comment: 32x32px is the image size